# reverse_lazy not redirecting to the correct link (adding a suffix)

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls, slug

so this is my class based function

```
class AddCommentView(CreateView):
model = Comment

form_class = CommentForm
template_name = 'app/add_comment.html'
def form_valid(self, form):
list_obj = List.objects.get(slug = self.kwargs['slug'])
        form.instance.list = list_obj
return super().form_valid(form)

success_url = reverse_lazy("app:list_detail", kwargs={'slug': List.slug})
```

once the comment is submitted I wanna go back to detailview page which is

http://127.0.0.1:8000/home/list/best-bangla-art-films2022-09-09-0505595309260000/

but its taking me to

http://127.0.0.1:8000/home/list/best-bangla-art-films2022-09-09-0505595309260000/comment/

any way i can solve this?

in my urls

(I have excluded irrelevant paths)

```
app_name = "app"
urlpatterns = [
path('', views.HomeView.as_view(),name='home'),
path('list/<slug:slug>/', TheirDetailView.as_view(),name='list_detail'),
path('list/<slug:slug>/comment/',AddCommentView.as_view(),name="add_comment"),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `success_url = reverse_lazy("app:list_detail", kwargs={'slug': List.slug})` to `success_url = reverse_lazy("app:list_detail", kwargs={'slug': list_obj.slug})`.
You should use the variable name, not the Model

Comment: just tried this. ``` class AddCommentView(CreateView):
    model = Comment
    
    form_class = CommentForm
    template_name = 'app/add_comment.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        list_obj = List.objects.get(slug = self.kwargs['slug'])
        form.instance.list = list_obj
        return super().form_valid(form)

    list_obj = List.objects.get(slug = self.kwargs['slug'])
    success_url = reverse_lazy("app:list_detail", kwargs={'slug': list_obj.slug})
    ```       . The problem is its getting the sug but not taking the slug to the list_detail url i want.

Comment: Try adding `*args` and `**kwargs` in your def. Something like this: `def form_valid(self, form, *args, **kwargs):`. By the way, I hope the code is indented correctly, I can't understand if is correctly indented from your code. Lastly, I would try, instead of using `reverse_lazy` with `redirect` function.